# When I start the game, it's spinning around and is unplayable

Tags: technical-issues, shelter

Lately, when I start a new game of *Shelter*, the game is spinning wildly in one direction and is basically unplayable.  How can I get this to stop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are two things to check (the second one solved my problem):

### Do you need to calibrate your controller?

Hit Win-R, then type joy.cpl and hit Enter.  Select the controller you're using, click Properties, and on the Settings tab you can click Calibrate... to make sure the control is properly centered and so forth.

### Are you getting interference from a different controller?

In addition to a couple of Xbox 360 controllers on my PC, I have a Logitech Extreme 3D Pro joystick attached.

There's a slider on this joystick.  It's just to the lower-left of the Logitech logo in the image below.

***Shelter* reads this slider as performing camera rotation.**  So if the slider is all the way up or down, the camera will rotate uncontrollably.  The solution is to move the slider in the middle (or just unplug the Logitech controller).

[image: Logitech Extreme 3D Pro]